# How to check if a vm is running on an esxi by command line?

Tags: vmware-esxi

How can i check, if a vm is actually running on one of my esxi hosts by command line?

I know, that i can ping it, when i have the ip adress at my hand, but that has to do with the things inside the vm.

Is there a vmware way?

Comment: Again, zero quality here, look at the documentation first please.

Comment: @Chopper3 I did look at the documentation, but could not find a command line parameter solving this, if it exists...

Comment: You seem way too lazy for this site and/or need to increase your reading level.

Comment: This question is just too lazy to be allowed to remain open.

Answer (score 2):

This is lazy.. you're basically asking "give me teh codez!"

Go read the documentation: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp

[image]

Comment: As i wrote above, I did look at the documentation and yes, i did look in exacly the ones you provided, but, shame on me, i could not find a command line parameter solving my problem. So i just wanted to ask the community, if anybody knows it...

Comment: Then how can you miss something like this? http://i.imgur.com/1DgqsUX.png